# Where is libc++ on OS X?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11

I have built my own libc++ and I usually include it with `-I /path/to/lib/include -L /path/to/lib/lib`. But now I have to share a project with someone else with a Mac and I want to hand them a Makefile™ that "just works"®.

Consider the following program:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    uint32_t nums[100];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        nums[i] = 666;
    }

    vector<int> hello{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    for_each(hello.begin(), hello.end(), [](int tal)
    {
        cout << tal << endl;
    });
}
```

When I compile it with `clang++ -o test test.cc` I naturally get errors that relate to missing `-std=c++11` flag. Ok, so lets add it `clang++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cc`. That gives several errors, one of which is

```
test.cc:15:17: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'vector<int>'
vector<int> hello{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

Ok, I need a C++11 capable C++ library.

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -o test test.cc 
test.cc:1:10: fatal error: 'algorithm' file not found
#include <algorithm>
```

My solution to this has been to use `-I` and `-L` pointing to my manually compiled libc++.

Assuming that the person I will share this with doesn't have that but has at least XCode. What can I do to make the above code copile? Surely OS X must ship with C++11 capabilities???

[EDIT]

Turns out that since I installed llvm with xcode from homwbrew that clang was showing up when I did `which clang`. I assumed that clang from homebrew would not get symlinked into `/usr/local/bin` but apparently it did. So I guess the lesson learnt (as so many times before) is to never assume but to RTFM!

Comment: Depends on the version of OSX as to whether the libstdc++ included supports some of c++11. I don't think all features are available as of yet even in the latest one.

Comment: This code compiles cleanly on the latest XCode (4.6.1) on Mountain Lion (clang-425.0.27) when the command line tools are installed

Comment: @Petesh Weird, I have Mountain Lion, fresh install from 2 days ago and latest XCode with command line tools installed.... What kind of flags do you pass to get it to compile?

Comment: @Petesh Turns out it wasn't so weird. I was using homebrew clang when I thought I was using XCode clang. Should have done a `which clang` as suggested by the accepted solution. Now, using XCode clang, I just have to specify `-std=c++11`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recent Xcode releases put both clang and libc++ headers inside of the Xcode.app.  Control click on it and choose "Show Package Contents" to navigate into this directory.

Ensure that your command line clang is the same one that is inside your Xcode.app:

```
$ which clang++
```

For me:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
```

and:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1
```

Comment: That did the trick! I should have known to do `which clang`... Turned out that my homebrew clang was the one that turned up. Using clang from within Xcode.app... solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 (15G1004)

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/
```