# How to fix error loading tidyverse library

Tags: r, installation

I am having trouble loading the `tidyverse` library. I am new to R. After installing packages using:

```
install.packages("tidyverse",dependencies = TRUE)
```

No problem thus far... but then I try to load the tidyverse library:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

I get the following:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
>    unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
>
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so, 6): Symbol not found: ___cxa_uncaught_exceptions
>     Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libc++.1.dylib
>     Expected in: /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
>    in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libc++.1.dylib

I have tried installing and uninstalling R, with no effect.

I'm using Version 1.1.463 – © 2009-2018 RStudio, Inc. for use with OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.4.

Comment: Seems like issues with your compiler. I don't use OS X so not familiar with how the compiler works or what dependencies you need but do try looking into libc++. [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981424/where-is-libc-on-os-x) and [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-load-most-packages-issue-with-libc-1-dylib/33051) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929612/fail-to-load-libraries-after-upgrading-r-to-3-6-0-on-mac).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fail to load libraries after upgrading R to 3.6.0 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929612/fail-to-load-libraries-after-upgrading-r-to-3-6-0-on-mac)

Comment: Hi NelsonGon and Bulat, thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Hi NelsonGon and Bulat, thank you for the suggestions. I am embarassed to say that I am to much of a newb to make any sense of the links NelsonGon has provided. The possible duplicate that Bulat has offered looks like the same error message as I get, but I follow the instructions in that thread with no success. I am getting a bit desperate now, as if I can't solve this problem I will have severe problems writing my confirmation for my PhD. If anyone can help, i would be hugely thankful!!!